# Change Facebook developer account for an iOS app - bundle identifier

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've developed an iOS app that is integrated with Facebook to allow users to log in using their FB accounts. That works fine.

The app is also supposed to use a web service developed by another company. Said web service also uses Facebook integration.

Both my app and the web service were developed using different Facebook developer accounts. Now it seems a major problem I've got needs both of these to be part of the same "Facebook application" which means they'd have to belong to the same Facebook developer account.

I asked the other company's developer to add a native iOS aspect to his Facebook app, gave him my app's bundle ID and received a Facebook app ID and secret in return. I made the appropriate changes to my app's Info tab in XCode - the bundle ID is the same one that I gave him, the FacebookAppID is the one I got from him and so is the URL Schemes thing (with an "fb" preceding the actual FBAppID).

However, when I try to log in using Facebook credentials in the app, I constantly get com.facebook.sdk error 2 which is explained in the console by this message: `FBSDKLog: System authorization failed:'The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id '. This may be caused by a mismatch between the bundle identifier and your app configuration on the server at developers.facebook.com/apps.`

Is there a step I'm missing in this transition of app between FB developer accounts? Could something else be the cause of the problem here? If my question is off-topic, please at least point me in the direction where I could get some answers.

Comment: Please make sure that the BundleID of "Native iOS App" of "facebook app" properly match with your Bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed - it turned out that the problem was exactly what the error message said: the bundle ID was different for both the application in XCode and in the Facebook developer account; that was because the developer from the other company made a spelling mistake (lower case instead of upper case letter) in the bundle ID.